# Java filename expansion library

Tags: java, file

I'm looking for a Java library that helps resolve file paths, for example a library that would do something like:

```
String abs = Files.expand("$HOME/.bashrc")
```

or

```
String abs = Files.expand("~/$OTHER_DIR/../file")
```

and resolve those to a file path. Does any such thing exist?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few examples of this on the web: http://www.apacheserver.net/q33040/Expand-environment-variables-in-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getEnv`. Example:

```
String variable = System.getenv("WINDIR");
System.out.println(variable);
```

To discover them all, use:

```
Map<String, String> variables = System.getenv();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : variables.entrySet())
{
   String name = entry.getKey();
   String value = entry.getValue();
   System.out.println(name + "=" + value);
}
```

Complete article in http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/get-environment-variables-in-java.html

Comment: I was thinking this would be something that's done commonly enough that there would be a library, but this is close.

Answer (score 0):

That will be a platform dependent solution. (%var% in windows, $var in unix etc). Could you just use system properties?